# parse error in function that is supposed to convert list to string - haskell

Tags: haskell

so my function 'flatten' is to take a list of characters and digits to a string

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten [] = []
flatten [(x,y):xs)] = x:(show y ++ flatten xs)
```

but I keep getting parse error, can anyone help me understand? Thanks.

```
 parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
18 | flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
   | ^
```

Comment: Likely this is because of something *before* the `flatten` function, for example an opening bracket/parenthesis, that has no closing counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile error likely originates from something *before* the `flatten` function, for example you forgot to close a bracket.

As for the `flatten` function itself, for the second clause you should not use square brackets, otherwise you define a pattern of a list of lists of 2-tuples. You thus use `(x, y):xs)` as pattern:

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten [] = []
flatten ((x,y):xs) = x : show y ++ flatten xs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flatten [(x,y):xs)] = x:(show y ++ flatten xs)
                 ^
```